# update database using ajax in mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

```
var loginCred = new Object();
loginCred.Username = $('#userName').val();
loginCred.Password = $('#password').val();
loginCred.RememberMe = $('#rememberMe').checked;

var myJsonObject = JSON.stringify(loginCred);

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Account/LogOnAjax/",
    data: myJsonObject,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        PostCredentialsSuccess(data);
    }

});
```

I try to develop application using mvc3.In here i want to update database using ajax. this my ajax request to post a form data.But I
want to catch this data in controller and update database using this
data.Please help me

Comment: `$('#rememberMe').checked;` should be `$('#rememberMe').is(':checked');` or $('#rememberMe')[0].checked;

Comment: So uh... your storing a username/password combination plain text in the dom?

Comment: Would you confirm whether data is posted to the Controller correctly?Share the "/Account/LogOnAjax/" Action code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stringify your object.

```
var myJsonObject = JSON.stringify(loginCred);
```

You have specified dataType: "json" so you can use loginCred

```
data: loginCred,
```

And try remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: "And try remove contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"" that worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem

```
data: myJsonObject,
```

use

```
data:{"jsondata":myJsonObject}
```

Comment: This is not PHP. The server side should have a strongly typed model for the model binder to work against.

Comment: I want to action method how I manupulate json data in action method